# Trouble Scraping Web Page With Malformed Content

Tags: c#, parsing, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have written c# code which utilizes the HtmlAgilityPack library in order to scrape a page located at: [World's Largest Urban Areas (Page 2)](http://www.mongabay.com/cities_urban_02.htm).  Unfortunately the page consists of malformed content.

I'm at an impasse on how to scrape this page.  The current code I have (appearing below) freezes on parsing the HTML:

```
 HtmlNodeCollection cityRecords = _htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='boldtable']//tr[position() != 1]");
 CityNodes = (from node in cityRecords.Descendants()
              where node.Name == "td"
              select node).ToList();
```

The goal is to parse each and every city listed on the page with each of the data points; nothing more.  Looking for recommendations on how to modify the above code or use another freely available library.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably stray away from screen scraping. You are already experience problems in why its bad practice - if not disingenuous or illegal. Try looking for a geographical / census api - then all you have to do is implement a simple REST client.

Comment: Thanks for the input Skawful - I totally agree. However I HAVE spent considerable time searching for just that and haven't had any luck. Now watch someone point out an API in the next 5 minutes :).
I should also add this is more of an exercise for me in learning the supporting technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the content through HTML Tidy before parsing it.

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for response so far.  Do you know if there is an equivalent .Net library?  I'd like to have the application download an HTML page (not just the one I cite in my question), run Html Tidy or an equivalent, and then process.

Comment: I'm not aware of a native one, but COM Interop should not be too difficult as long as speed is not a major issue.

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20505/0/page/2 is one link.

Comment: I have found one, but I know almost nothing about it:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/