# is it possible to fix the problem in HtmlAgilityPack when there is a not closed html tag?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

well i have the following problem.
the html i have is malformed and i have problems with selecting nodes using html agility pack when this is the case.
the code is below:

```
string strHtml = @"
<html>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A1_2 String_A1_2</p>
    <p><strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B1_2 String_B1_2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A2_2 <String_A2_2> asdas</p>
    <p><strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B2_2 String_B2_2</p>
  </div>
</html>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument objHtmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
objHtmlDocument.LoadHtml(strHtml);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection colnodePs = objHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
List<string> lststrText = new List<string>();
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode nodeP in colnodePs)
{
  lststrText.Add(nodeP.InnerHtml);
}
```

the problem is that String_A2_2 is enclosed in brackets.
so htmlagility pack returns 5 strings instead of 4 in the lststrText.
so is it possible to let htmlagility pack return element 3 as 
`"<strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A2_2 <String_A2_2> asdas"`?
or maybe i can do some preprocessing to close the element?
the current content of lststrText is

```
lststrText[0] = "<strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A1_2 String_A1_2"  
lststrText[1] = "<strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B1_2 String_B1_2"  
lststrText[2] = ""  
lststrText[3] = ""  
lststrText[4] = "<strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B2_2 String_B2_2"
```

Comment: Do you know the names of the tags you want to include, or do you want to keep all open tags as text?

Comment: i want to keep all open tags as text

Comment: Html Agility Pack cannot do this. It parses one character a time, and doesn't really have a notion of backtracking. It will however close tags needed, but this as you experienced results in a different output compared to what you want.

The best approach would be to do some pre-processing.

If you know the names or patterns of the tags you want to keep, it's quite easy to modify the parsing code to keep the tags like: <String_A2_2></String_A2_2>, which later can be replaced for your output.

Maybe it's easier to fix the malformed html you are processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most html parsers try to build a working DOM, meaning dangling tags are not accepted. They will be converted, or closed in some way.

If only selecting the nodes is of importance to you, and speed and huge amounts of data is not an issue, you could grab all your <p> tags with a regular expression instead:

```
Regex reMatchP = new Regex(@"<(p)>.*?</\1>");
foreach (Match m in reMatchP.Matches(strHtml))
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

This regular expression assumes the <p> tags are well formed and closed.

If you are to run this Regex a lot in your program you should declare it as:

```
static Regex reMatchP = new Regex(@"<(p)>.*?</\1>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

[Edit: Agility pack change]

If you want to use HtmlAgility pack you can modify the PushNodeEnd function in HtmlDocument.cs:

```
if (HtmlNode.IsCDataElement(CurrentNodeName()))
{
   _state = ParseState.PcData;
   return true;
}

// new code start
if ( !AllowedTags.Contains(_currentnode.Name) )
{
    close = true;
}
// new code end
```

where AllowedTags would be a list of all known tags: b, p, br, span, div, etc.

the output is not 100% what you want, but maybe close enough?

```
<strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A1_2 String_A1_2
<strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B1_2 String_B1_2
<strong>Elem_A</strong>String_A2_2 <ignorestring_a2_2></ignorestring_a2_2> asdas
<strong>Elem_B</strong>String_B2_2 String_B2_2
```

Comment: regular expressions are not an option to parsehtml.

Comment: thanks,i will take a look and see if that will fix the problem.

Comment: wow it works, how did u do it ? did you try to understand all the code of html agility pack?

Comment: I've worked with html parsing in .Net for a long time, so it wasn't too hard to debug the code to see what was happening. I'm glad the solution works for you even though it adds a closing tag :)

Comment: yeah that explains it , because when i tried to debug htmlagility pack i got lost, anyway you showed me that its possible so i think i will try in the future to fix this problem. but i got other tasks to do right now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TidyNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908378/trouble-scraping-web-page-with-malformed-content/1908535#1908535) to do the pre/postprocessing you allude to. Can you edit your answer to explain why that wouldnt be applicable in your case?

Comment: well i didnt try TidyNet bacause i wasnt able to let it work.
but i tried SgmlReader http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader but i didnt work too.